# What do I need for Java Socket programming?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Socket programming in Java to make a game I created playable via network. I have never done much network programming so the subject is a bit confusing. In php I use apache to test my aplications on a local server. What do I need to install to be able to run network applications with Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to install anything special. [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) has been in the standard JDK since version 1.0.

See [socket tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) to get started.

If you want to test how the communication works between processes, then simply start >1 processes in the same machine. In principle it works similarly over any network.

Comment: For an instant copy-paste-go code example [this one is OK](http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html)